# Use Anchor after POST Form Submission

Tags: php, html, web-applications

**I need to let the page loads at specific label within a page after user clicks the button Post.**

Note: i'm using PHP

*Form Code Sample:*

```
<form action="po.php?id=44" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="here" value="#here" />
   <input name="btn_send" type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>
```

The page should land somewhere in the page which has one title in between

as seen below

*Code Sample:*

```
<a name="here"></a>
<p>Total Number of Posts 55</p>
```

As you see, the place i land is a regular label text, not hyperlink. Therefore, i put the anchor line as an indicator just before the title.

**Problem:**

***Page doesn't land where i put (name="here"). The page lands to the top. Is there easy way to make it land at ( name="here")?***

Comment: Try changing name="here" to id="here" :/

Comment: try `action="po.php?id=44#here"`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply include the fragment in your form's `action` attribute, eg

```
<form method="post" action="po.php?id=44#here">
```

Also, using ID attributes as fragment locations is much nicer. Lose the empty anchor and change your paragraph to...

```
<p id="here">Total number of Posts 55</p>
```

Comment: <p id="here"> would also represent an id of css attribute, wouldn't it?

Comment: @user311509 If you mean *"can I use the ID to select this element in CSS"*, the answer is "yes", eg `#here { color: red; }`

Comment: @user311509 it can, but why would this be a problem?

Comment: @user311509 I can only hope you *actually* use a better identifier than "here". How about "total-posts"?

Comment: Interesting, i didn't know that id can be used for dual tasks, Anchor + Attribute....here is just a temporary one.

Comment: Great answer, who knew!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<form action="po.php?id=44#here" method="POST">
   <input name="btn_send" type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>
```

And put this on the target page:

```
<a id="here"></a>
<p>Total Number of Posts 55</p>
```

Comment: It should've had id instead of name + the action part. id by itself doesn't help.

Comment: I haven't missed any of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Location: url#fragment");
```

Comment: There are no alternatives. A POST request should always by followed by a GET redirect, no matter of what patterns you are fond of.