# Load page at certain position

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, position

I'm building a wordpress site where I want the user to be faced a specific part of the page when loading it the first time. I do not want that the user lands on the top of the code in index.php. For example:

```
<body>
<div id="firstcontent"></div>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="secondcontent"></div>
</body>
```

In this case, I would like that the header and secondcontent div are shown when loading the page. If you then scroll UP you would se "firstcontent". Is this possible?

Comment: Use anchors?  And by anchors I mean use the "#" in the URL and mark your code with anchors.  Something like this question should get you what you want:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079575/use-anchor-after-post-form-submission

Comment: There's a few options, but probably the most common solution: Anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).scrollTop($('#header').offset.top);
});
```

When the page is first loaded it will attempt to scroll the document to the top of the Header Element. This should work as long as your page has enough content to be taller than the window.