# html / javascript - jump to anchor not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have an onClick function directing to an anchor when my button is clicked. When you click the button you can see the # appear in the url and the page quickly jumps to the anchor, but then the # in the url disappears and the page jumps back to the top. I was wondering if anybody knows what is causing this and how to fix it so that the page stays at the anchor.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name='search' onClick="location.href='index.php#results'">Search</button>
```

then later in the page...

```
<a id="results"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've attached your click event listener to a submit button.

Presumably, it is inside a form.

Clicking it causes the event to fire, the JS to run, and then the form to submit (because that is the purpose of a submit button).

If you want to link to another part of the page, use a link. If you want it to look like a button, use CSS.

```
<a href="#results" class="btn btn-primary">Scroll to results</a>
```

---

If your goal is to:

1. Submit the form
2. Load the page with the results
3. **Then** scroll to the anchor

Then see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079575/use-anchor-after-post-form-submission).

Answer (score -1):

You need to use button inside `<a>` tag

```
<a href="index.php#results">
  Search <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name='search' />
</a>
```

Comment: This is invalid HTML. Links may not appear inside buttons. (And it doesn't make sense to put a link inside a button).